# value of state increment twice in reducer.js file

Tags: reactjs, firebase

***Order is an array of Objects and there is a key 'count' inside each variable. When ADD_ITEM_IN_ORDER case is executed than the count of particular object should be increment by 1. But, in this case, when the particular item is already present in the array than the value of count of that item incrementing by 2, which should not happen(it should increment by 1).***

reducer.js

```
export const initialState = {
  Order: [],
  };
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
      
    case "ADD_ITEM_IN_ORDER":
      const tempOrder1 = [...state.Order];
      const index1 = state.Order.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.item.id);
        
      if (index1 >= 0) {
        console.log("before",tempOrder1[index1].Count);
        tempOrder1[index1].Count += 1;
        return { ...state, Order: tempOrder1 };
      }
      else {
        console.log("New item added");
        return {
          ...state,
          Order: [...state.Order, action.item]
        };
      }
    
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
  
  export default reducer;
```

***action file***

```
import React from 'react';
import VegIcon from '../Images/VegIcon.png';
import NonVegIcon from '../Images/NonVegIcon.png';
import { useStateValue } from '../StateProvider';
import { db } from '../firebase';

const CartMenu = (props) => {
    const [{ Order }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    
    const add = () => {
        
                dispatch({
                    type: "ADD_ITEM_IN_ORDER",
                    item: {
                    id: props.id,
                    menuCollectionName:props.menuCollectionName,    
                    VegNonV: props.VegNonV,
                    Menu: props.Menu,
                    Price: props.Price,
                    Count: 1,
                    // RestuarantId: props.restuarantId
                    }
                });
                console.log(Order);
            
    };
    const remove = () => { 
        
        dispatch({
            type: "REMOVE_ITEM_FROM_ORDER",
            item: {
                id: props.id,  // id of a dish
                restuarantId: props.restuarantId
            }
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className='Menu_Display'>
            <div className='Menu_Display_subsection1'>
            {props.VegNonV === "Veg" ?
                <img className="Menu_Veg_NonVeg" src={VegIcon} />
                :
                <img className="Menu_Veg_NonVeg" src={NonVegIcon} />
            }
                <div className='Menu_Name'>{props.Menu}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="Menu_Add_Button" >
                <div className="Menu_minus" onClick={remove}>−</div>
                    <span>{props.Count}</span>
                    <div className="Menu_plus" onClick={add}>+</div>
            </div>
            <div className='Menu_Price'>
                <span></span>
                <span>₹{Math.round(props.Price * props.Count * 100) / 100}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
 };

export default CartMenu;
```

***StateProvider.js***

```
//setup data layer 
// we need this to track the basket data

import React,{createContext,useContext,useReducer} from 'react';

export const StateContext  = createContext();

//Build Provider 
export const StateProvider = ({reducer,initialState,children}) =>
(
    <StateContext.Provider value = {useReducer(reducer,initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

The context API broadcasts updates when it notices a change in the value. Since you are invoking `useReducer` within the value props, that returns an array (state value and dispatch function), it is this, that is likely causing double dispatch. I recommend you re-write your Provider logic.

```
import React,{createContext,useContext,useReducer} from 'react';

export const StateContext  = createContext({ //Make sure to export this
  Order:[], //Will be consuimg the state value from here
  addItem:(arg)=>{} //This function will be hooked to a dispatch function below
});

//Build Provider 
export const StateProvider = ({reducer,initialState,children}) =>
{  
    const [state,dispatchFn] = useReducer(reducer,initialState)
    
    const addItemHandler = (item) => {
         dispatchFn(item)
    }
    return(<StateContext.Provider value = {{Order:state.Order,addItem:addItemHandler}}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>)
};
```

You can then wrap your root component with the context provider component `StateProvider` so that all the components can access the state values.
In your `index.js` wrap the component like this:

```
import {StateProvider} from './path/to/provider'

ReactDOM.render(<StateProvider><App/></StateProvider>,doucment.getElementById("root"))
```

You can then use the context state and dispatch function from `useContext` hook by, passing the context variable. 
In your action file:

```
import {useContext},React from 'react'; //Import use context
import {StateContext} from './path/to/state/context'
import VegIcon from '../Images/VegIcon.png';
import NonVegIcon from '../Images/NonVegIcon.png';

import { db } from '../firebase';

const CartMenu = (props) => {
    const order_ctx = useContext(StateContext);
    
    const add = () => {
        
                order_ctx.addItem({
                    type: "ADD_ITEM_IN_ORDER",
                    item: {
                    id: props.id,
                    menuCollectionName:props.menuCollectionName,    
                    VegNonV: props.VegNonV,
                    Menu: props.Menu,
                    Price: props.Price,
                    Count: 1,
                    // RestuarantId: props.restuarantId
                    }
                });
                console.log(Order);
            
    };
    const remove = () => { 
        
        order_ctx.rmItem({                //Note: rmItem method is not added to createContext, but this is just to demonstrate how state update methods can be invoked by using the context instance.
            type: "REMOVE_ITEM_FROM_ORDER",
            item: {
                id: props.id,  // id of a dish
                restuarantId: props.restuarantId
            }
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className='Menu_Display'>
            <div className='Menu_Display_subsection1'>
            {props.VegNonV === "Veg" ?
                <img className="Menu_Veg_NonVeg" src={VegIcon} />
                :
                <img className="Menu_Veg_NonVeg" src={NonVegIcon} />
            }
                <div className='Menu_Name'>{props.Menu}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="Menu_Add_Button" >
                <div className="Menu_minus" onClick={remove}>−</div>
                    <span>{props.Count}</span>
                    <div className="Menu_plus" onClick={add}>+</div>
            </div>
            <div className='Menu_Price'>
                <span></span>
                <span>₹{Math.round(props.Price * props.Count * 100) / 100}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
 };

export default CartMenu;
```

And also since, your state contains only an array of orders, you can just return the updated array without having to override the previous state.

In your reducer:

```
case "ADD_ITEM_IN_ORDER":
      const tempOrder1 = [...state.Order];
      const index1 = state.Order.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.item.id);
        
      if (index1 >= 0) {
        console.log("before",tempOrder1[index1].Count);
        tempOrder1[index1].Count += 1;
        return { Order: [...tempOrder1] }; //Return updated array only
      }
      else {
        console.log("New item added");
        return {
          Order: [...state.Order, action.item] //Return updated array only
        };
      }
    
      default:
        return state;
    }
```